# BufferedReader skipping each second line

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

Reading from a CSV and it skips every second line. I have two CSV files, one for users, one for properties - the key ID is user.

```
    String userName;
    static String breakLine = "\n--------------------\n";
        /**
        * Method to create a new user in a CSV File
        * @param sFileName
        * @param user
        */
   static void writeToCsvFile(String sFileName, User user)
   {
    try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);


        writer.append(user.displayUserName()); // get username from userinput
        writer.append(","); // tabs to next record

        writer.append(user.getPassword()); //gets password from userinput
        writer.append(","); //tabs to next record
        writer.append("\n");

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        System.out.print("\nUser Successfully Created\n");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 

   }





   /**
    * Class to read User information from specified CSV file
    * @param sFileName
    * @param user
    * @throws FileNotFoundException
    */
   static boolean readFromCsvFile(String sFileName, User user) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       String thisLine;
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sFileName));


        try
        {

        //  thisLine = reader.readLine();
          //System.out.print(thisLine);


           while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String userDetails[] = thisLine.split(",");

                    if ((user.displayUserName().equals(userDetails[0])))
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nUser <-" + user.displayUserName() + " -> exists! Logging In\n\n");
                        return true;
                    }

                    else if ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) == null)
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nNo User Details Matching Those Entered Exist. Please Register or Recheck Details.");
                        return false;
                    }
               }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nUser does not exist\n"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 


        finally{
            try
            {   reader.close();
            }catch (IOException e){}}
        return false;
            }


   static void writeToPropertyFile(String sFileName, Property property)
   {

    try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName, true);



        writer.append(property.getUser()); // get username from userinput
        writer.append(","); // tabs to next record

        writer.append(property.getAddress()); //gets address from userinput
        writer.append(","); //tabs to next record

        writer.append(property.getValue()); //gets property value from userinput
        writer.append(","); //tabs to next record

        writer.append(property.getLocation()); //gets property type from userinput
        writer.append(","); //tabs to next record

        writer.append(property.getResidenceStatus()); //gets residence status from userinput
        writer.append(","); //tabs to next record

        writer.append(property.getPaymentStatus()); //gets payment status from userinput
        writer.append(","); //tabs to next record

        writer.append(property.totalTax(property.privateResidence));
        writer.append(",");

        writer.append("\n");

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        System.out.print("\nProperty Successfully Saved to " + property.getUser() + "\n");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 

   }

/**
 * Method to read and print all properties belonging to a user
 * @param sFileName
 * @param property
 * @param userName
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
static void readFromPropertyFile(String sFileName, String userName) throws FileNotFoundException
{

       String thisLine;
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sFileName));


        try
        {
            //thisLine = reader.readLine(); //skips first line in CSV


           while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {

                    String propertyDetails[] = thisLine.split(",");



                    if (propertyDetails[0].equals(userName))
                    {
                    System.out.print("\nUser: " + propertyDetails[0] + "\nAddress: " + propertyDetails[1] + "\nEst. Value: " + propertyDetails[2]
                            + "\nLocation Cat: " + propertyDetails[3] + "\nPrivate Residence: " + propertyDetails[4] + "\nTax Paid: " + propertyDetails[5] +  "\nTax Due: " + propertyDetails[6] + breakLine);

                    }

                    else if ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) == null)
                        System.out.print("\nNo Further Properties Found For This User\n");


               }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nProperties do not exist\n"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        finally{
            try
            {   reader.close();
            }catch (IOException e){}}
            }


}
```

I was running it with the following users

```
Chris,password
Michelle,password
Zach,password
etc (on seperate lines, seperated by appending \n at the end of the input stage)
```

Every odd numbered one was working and detecting that the user was logged in, each second one is skipping. I read up and I don't think I have a .nextLine() running skipping as in this link but I only starting using CSVs and BufferedReader on Friday!

[BufferedReader readLine skipping every second line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200462/bufferedreader-readline-skipping-every-second-line)

Comment: `}catch (IOException e){}}`  Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  That code reads like it was formatted by your dog, and I don't speak 'psychotic fox terrier'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its skipping every second line because you are reading two lines in every iteration and only using the odd ones.

I suggest instead using

```
while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null) { // only read once per loop.
    String propertyDetails[] = thisLine.split(",");
    if (propertyDetails[0].equals(userName)) {
        System.out.print("\nUser: " + propertyDetails[0] + "\nAddress: " + propertyDetails[1] + "\nEst. Value: " + propertyDetails[2]
                + "\nLocation Cat: " + propertyDetails[3] + "\nPrivate Residence: " + propertyDetails[4] + "\nTax Paid: " + propertyDetails[5] + "\nTax Due: " + propertyDetails[6] + breakLine);

    }
}
// out side the loop.
System.out.print("\nNo Further Properties Found For This User\n");
```